# set color from datasource like you would set argumentField or valueField?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js

Given the following data, can I utilize the "color" field to set the series color?

```
{ severity: "minor", count: 30, color: 'yellow' },
{ severity: "major", count: 23, color: 'orange' },
{ severity: "critical", count: 12, color: 'red' },
{ severity: "resolved", count: 35, color: 'green' }
```

And here is the chart definition.  I can use argumentField to specify severity and valueField to specify count, but there is no such parameter for color:

```
dxPieChart: {
    dataSource: dsAlarmsBySeverity,
    size: {
        width: 275,
        height: 150
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'doughnut',
        argumentField: 'severity',
        valueField: 'count',
        label: {
            visible: false
        }
    }]
}
```

The color just needs to be based on the severity, so I'll accept any answers that accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, crap.  Just noticed the tag didn't show up.  Fixing...

Comment: cool, deleted my answer reply, hope you get there, the closest I saw was that a 'palette' is defined in an array - this got me thinking there may be some connection between the selected 'severity' array number and the palette array number. - just thoughts.

Comment: chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/dxPieChart/Configuration#palette

Comment: I saw that, but I can't be sure what order the severity will be in the array and thus the series...

Comment: I have only touched chart js. How about creating the 'palette' array dynamically by employing another function to create it, loop through grab the color key and then - DevExpress.viz.core.registerPalette('mypalette', dynamicmadepaletteArray); ?

Comment: That's a pretty good idea.  I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: I like Rob's idea. ChartJS has API for points customization, but unfortunately it only works for dxChart http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartsadvancedfeaturescustomizepoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows, you need to add the `customize_point` field with indicated return:

```
dxPieChart: {
    dataSource: dsAlarmsBySeverity,
    ...,
    customizePoint: function (point) {
        return {
            color: dsAlarmsBySeverity[point.index].color
        }
    }
}
```